# Plot multiple Excel sheets into one graph without repeating read.xlsx

Tags: r, excel, plot, xlsx

I have a excel file with three sheets: sheet 1, sheet 2, sheet 3.
Each sheet has column x and y.
I want to put the three plots x-y into one plot like below

[image]

What I did was read each sheets separately, and 'plot + lines'.

Is there any loop method to do this? Because I'll have more than three sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a good approach here would be to read each sheet into a list of data frames, stack them into a single data frame that includes an identifier for the source sheet, and then plot using ggplot2.

Here's an example with a simple Excel file called `test.xlsx` that I created. It has three sheets, each with four rows of data, as illustrated below. The code assumes that the Excel file is in the current working directory. If not, provide the appropriate path to the file when you read the data. I've used the `readxl` package to read the data. This method generalizes to an Excel workbook with any number of sheets with the same column names (though you could do additional processing to deal with different column names in different sheets).

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Get sheet names
sht = excel_sheets("test.xlsx")

sht
```

> ```
> [1] "Sheet 3" "Sheet 2" "Sheet1"
> ```

```
# Read each sheet into a list
df = lapply(setNames(sht, sht), function(s) read_excel("test.xlsx", sheet=s))

df
```

> ```
> $`Sheet 3`
>       x     y
> 1     1    10
> 2     2    11
> 3     3    12
> 4     4    13
>
> $`Sheet 2`
>       x     y
> 1     1     5
> 2     2     6
> 3     3     7
> 4     4     8
>
> $Sheet1
>       x     y
> 1     1     1
> 2     2     2
> 3     3     3
> 4     4     4
> ```

```
# Convert to a single data frame with a column for the source sheet
df = bind_rows(df, .id="Sheet")

# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(x,y,colour=Sheet)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,max(df$y))) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Appreciate a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Another way could be to use `library(xlsx)`, it has function called `getSheets` which can tell you the name and number of sheets you are having in a workbook. I am reading the names of the sheets and then using them to create a list of data for all the sheets. I combine these data into a long format to be used with ggplot later.

```
library(xlsx)
setwd("/Users/pradeepkumar/Desktop/Misc") ###set your working directory where your data resides
sheetname <- getSheets(loadWorkbook("Workbook1.xlsx"))
s1 <- lapply(names(sheetname),function(x)read.xlsx("Workbook1.xlsx",sheetName = x))
names(s1) <- names(sheetname)
final_data <- data.frame(do.call("rbind",s1 ))
sheets <- rownames(final_data)
sheets <- gsub("\\.\\d{1,}","",sheets)
final_data$sheets <- sheets
rownames(final_data) <- NULL
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=final_data,aes(x=x,y=y,color=sheets)) + geom_line()
```

For example I have workbook (Workbook1.xlsx) with three sheets( 1, 2 and 3)

I have three different dataset in each of them with x and y as variables. Using the above code I can get a plot as below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @futong Hi Welcome to SO, It seems you are little new and you might have mistakenly reselect the accept answer, to my solution, `however I request you to accept the eipi10 solution` as he was the first one who posted the solution, I understand you can't upvote to my answer due to your low points, but a thanks is more than enough for me.  Please change the solution marked to epi10. It is a great community . Thanks

Comment: Actually, I think it's better if @futong selects the answer that works best for him, rather than the answer that happened to be first. If using `xlsx` fits better with his workflow, then he should select your answer.

Comment: Many thanks for both of you. I thought I could select two. I use both code to plot, both codes work. Thanks again for saving my day!